# SQL Server : variable with EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck at a point with my queries.

I have a table with some project, first I'd like to check if All of my projects are in my table and store the result in a variable

So I have something like:

```
  SELECT [ProjectID]
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[Project]
  EXCEPT
  SELECT [ProjecID]
  FROM  [DB].[dbo].[CurrentProject]
  WHERE ResourceId = (SELECT ResourceId
                      FROM [DB].[dbo].[Timesheets]
                      WHERE @TimesheetUID = TimesheetId)
```

If I try to use

```
DECLARE @STOREVAR UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

@STOREVAR = SELECT [ProjectID]
            FROM [DB].[dbo].[Project]
            EXCEPT
            SELECT [ProjecID]
            FROM [DB].[dbo].[CurrentProject]
            WHERE ResourceId = (SELECT ResourceId
                                FROM [DB].[dbo].[Timesheets]
                                WHERE @TimesheetUID = TimesheetId)
```

I need to store in my variable because after that, I have to do a IF with `@storevar`

It's not working, have you any idea of how could I do that?

Comment: Do you mean `select @StoreVar = ProjectId from ...`? That will work if you are certain the the query will never return more than one value. Tip: "It's not working" isn't much to go on. If you read that would you ask "How does it fail?" "I get an error." "Are you at liberty to disclose it?" "Yes" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need table variable instead :

```
DECLARE @STOREVAR TABLE ( [ProjectID]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO @STOREVAR ([ProjectID])
       SELECT [ProjectID]
       FROM [DB].[dbo].[Project]
       EXCEPT
       SELECT [ProjecID]
       FROM  [DB].[dbo].[CurrentProject]
       WHERE ResourceId = (SELECT ResourceId
                           FROM [DB].[dbo].[Timesheets]
                           WHERE @TimesheetUID=TimesheetId
                          );
```